# How do I set row and column in a GridLayout when working with components?

Tags: qml

I would like to fill a GridLayout with different Components which are depending on the modelData retrieved by a simple array model.

```
Item {
    id: root
    property var xdata: [
        {"row": 1, "col": 1, "type": "A"},
        {"row": 2, "col": 2, "type": "B"},
        {"row": 3, "col": 3, "type": "C"}
    ]

    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        width: 300
        height: 300
        rows: 3
        columns: 3

        Repeater {
            model: root.xdata
            delegate: Component {
                Loader {
                    sourceComponent: switch(modelData["type"]) {
                        case "A": return test_a
                        case "B": return test_b
                        case "C": return test_c
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Component {
            id: test_a

            Rectangle { 
                Layout.row: 1
                Layout.column: 1
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "red" 
            }
        }

        Component {
            id: test_b

            Rectangle {
                Layout.row: 2
                Layout.column: 2
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "green"
            }
        }
        Component {
            id: test_c

            Rectangle {
                Layout.row: 3
                Layout.column: 3
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "blue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine in automatic order, but when I set (staticly or dynamically) the components attached property Layout.row or Layout.column, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT/REWRITE]

Generally, when using `Layout`, it's best to use `Layout.preferredWidth` and `Layout.preferredHeight` instead of `width` and `height`. Also, I implemented `DelegateChooser` instead of `Loader`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels
Page {
    property var xdata: [
        {"row": 1, "col": 1, "type": "A"},
        {"row": 2, "col": 2, "type": "B"},
        {"row": 3, "col": 3, "type": "C"}
    ]
    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        width: 300
        height: 300
        Repeater {
            model: xdata
            delegate: DelegateChooser {
                role: "type"
                DelegateChoice { roleValue: "A"; TestA { } }
                DelegateChoice { roleValue: "B"; TestB { } }
                DelegateChoice { roleValue: "C"; TestC { } }
            }
        }
    }
}


// TestA.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Rectangle {
    Layout.row: modelData.row
    Layout.column: modelData.col
    Layout.preferredWidth: 100
    Layout.preferredHeight: 100
    color: "red"
}

// TestB.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Rectangle {
    Layout.row: modelData.row
    Layout.column: modelData.col
    Layout.preferredWidth: 100
    Layout.preferredHeight: 100
    color: "green"
}

// TestC.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Rectangle {
    Layout.row: modelData.row
    Layout.column: modelData.col
    Layout.preferredWidth: 100
    Layout.preferredHeight: 100
    color: "blue"
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAFTXic3VI9b4MwEN35FZbniHxtdApEaocOTVS1Q9XBgStYBUyNaYoi/nvP2KFOyJKOuQGd37078e4eLyohFdmoTcPjT4+fPP1IlEqKvD7HH1krGuXAfs52tf9V5IVIAPlPLAVy8AhGJUUFUrXkm0nykzDFAvLWV3QcqBR7GpD5hNBY5DZTbQWY0hXtJiPqYqAuHGp4ibocqEuHGtGuZ77333vJE6PH/rAOngQkxcIA7HmiMhwzmw1QBjzN1Cm2hQqYAumM0tFvJTDqTwoIQ4oNAVnbLMqEqEcDdOAhkGdUjIpOO49x9T37heUN9Gu8I89QqxXiHemuaw5tc/if5sg2Rxea/14m67zO87zp1PyqNtOZ7a515xZixco0PzrR4D5aIzAXWeM59NOtol2aonQJiLiESsIHSAnJq7HE3J7/vPxg7XGs4xghcSVYolqpFRrerNBUApSu1Ohmpe7Q7aj0F7EvmRQ=)

Comment: But what is the difference between adding components via repeater than adding the components directly into the grid? If you add it directly it looks as expected, even without defining the gap areas.

Comment: @kjub i rewrote my answer. I think the issue you're having is you're using `width` and `height` when you should be using `Layout.preferredWidth` and `Layout.preferredHeight`.